# Regex for multiple matches

Tags: regex, powershell

I am struggling to find a regex that matches all fieldnames in a SQL statement that is assigned to a string variable like this:

```
sqlText := "Select Nummer,"
sqlText += "Bez,"
sqlText += "Buchstabe,"
sqlText += "Maske,"
sqlText += "Zaehlkarte,"
sqlText += "Verteilart,"
sqlText += "Turnus,"
sqlText += "Verfart "
sqlText += "From AzStamm order by Nummer"
```

What I have come up with so far is

```
Select\s+([A-Za-z]+),
```

for the pattern.

What I want are all the field names like Nummer,Bez,Buchstabe etc.

I am using PowerShell but it could be C# (or probably Java or PHP) as well:

```
[Regex]::Matches($sql, $Muster,[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
```

I am probably missing something in the pattern (but I assume that the regex is greedy per default).

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

If the column names are always consisting of only letters, you could use:

```
select ((?:\p{L}+,\s*)*\p{L}+) from
```

... to grab the comma-separated list of names between `select` and `from`:

```
$sqlText  = "Select Nummer,"
$sqlText += "Bez,"
$sqlText += "Buchstabe,"
$sqlText += "Maske,"
$sqlText += "Zaehlkarte,"
$sqlText += "Verteilart,"
$sqlText += "Turnus,"
$sqlText += "Verfart "
$sqlText += "From AzStamm order by Nummer"

if($sqlText -match 'select ((?:\p{L}+,\s*)*\p{L}+) from '){
  $ColumnNames = $Matches[1].Split(",") |ForEach-Object Trim
}
else{
  Write-Error "Couldn't extract column names"
}
```

`$ColumnNames` will be an array of column name strings

Comment: another upvote for giving a reason for using the simplified foreach-object syntax - but works great!

Comment: I'm actually surprised that not more people use `ForEach-Object` for method invocation, super useful :D

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what syntax that is, but in PowerShell you would create the $sqText more like

```
$sqText = 'Select Nummer,Bez,Buchstabe,Maske,Zaehlkarte,Verteilart,Turnus,Verfart From AzStamm order by Nummer'
```

Then you can do this:

```
$fieldnames = $sqlText -replace '^Select\s+(.*)\s+From.*$', '$1' -split ','
```

to obtain an array with the field names:

```
Nummer
Bez
Buchstabe
Maske
Zaehlkarte
Verteilart
Turnus
Verfart
```

Comment: The language is X# but it could be any text. But the quotes are necessary within $sqlText so I don't get the field names with this. But using -replace instead of [Regex]::Matches() is a good idea. I haven't thought about that. Great, thank you for this approach.

Comment: @PeterXX What do you mean _the quotes are necessary within $sqlText_ ? If you print out your X# style `sqlText` variable, it wil read exactly the same as this `Select Nummer,Bez,Buchstabe,Maske,Zaehlkarte,Verteilart,Turnus,Verfart From AzStamm order by Nummer` won't it? Where are the quetes inside?

Comment: The quotes are part of the source code I would like to process. The problem is/was that I don't wanted to reformat the source code. But with the help of Mathias R Jessen I was able to solve the small problem. Thanks!